# How to fix MongoDB geo keys error with unknown GeoJSON type error?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, geometry, coordinates, geojson

I'm receiving the following error when running a query in Mongo:

> "errmsg" : "Can't extract geo keys: …[removed unnecessary elements]… unknown GeoJSON type: { coordinates: [ -75.17886559999999, 39.9451937 ] }

I've updated the schema to include 2dsphere, per the below:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.promise = Promise;

const listingSchema = new Schema({
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  title: { type: String, unique: false, required: false },
  parkingtype: { type: String, unique: false, required: false },
  photo: { type: String, unique: false, required: false },
  price: { type: Number, unique: false, required: false },
  address: { type: String, unique: false, required: false },
  city: { type: String, unique: false, required: false },
  state: { type: String, unique: false, required: false },
  zipcode: { type: Number, unique: false, required: false },
  streetName: { type: String, unique: false, required: false },
  neighborhood: { type: String, unique: false, required: false },
  location: {
    type: { 
      type: String,
      enum: ['Point'],
      required: false 
      },
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number]
    } 
  }
});

listingSchema.index({location: '2dsphere'}); // <-- already added index

const Listing = mongoose.model("Listing", listingSchema);
module.exports = Listing;
```

This is the error I get back in my terminal (see bold):

> errmsg:
>   'error processing query: ns=parky.listingsTree: GEONEAR  field=location maxdist=2000 isNearSphere=0\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n **planner returned error :: caused by :: unable to find index for $geoNear query'**,
>   code: 291,
>   codeName: 'NoQueryExecutionPlans',
>   name: 'MongoError',
>   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }

Finally, for reference, this is my controllers file, and the query that is being run:

```
findAllNear: function(req, res) {
    var long = req.query.data[0]
    var lat = req.query.data[1]

    var floatLong = parseFloat(long); // longitude comes through as string from url params, so it's converted to a float 
    var floatLat = parseFloat(lat); // same with latitude 

    db.Listing.syncIndexes().then((index) => {
      console.log("indexes:" , index); 

    }); // added this snippet to see that the location index was 2d


    db.Listing.find(
      {location:
        {$near: 
          {$maxDistance: 2000,
            $geometry: {
              type: "Point",
              coordinates: [floatLong, floatLat]
            }
          }
        }
    })
      .find((error, results) => { if (error) console.log(error);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(results, 0, 2))})
      .then(data => res.json(data))
      .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err))

  }
```

Comment: `location.type` must be set to `required`